# Distribute Load

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a database with 5 email addresses, and i have a contact form.

Each time a user submits the contact form, the form will need to submit the details to one of my stored email addresses. This i can handle but i start getting confused as to how i will get it to *share submissions with the emails.

IE. I need to share the load between the email addresses. each time the contact form is submitted it will need to send to the next email address in my table. Then start from the beginning when it reaches the last email.

Sorry if this is a serious beginner question, i just cant seem to think of the best way to do this.

Comment: Having 5 users share the same POP account would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of an extra column in the email table called `sendcount` with default 0. In the script where you want to find out which address to send an email to, do the following:

```
//Get email with least counts
$query="SELECT * FROM emails ORDER BY sendcount ASC LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$object=mysql_fetch_object($result); //This will store the required email address in $object->email

//Send email...

//Increase counter by one
$query="UPDATE emails SET sendcount=sendcount+1 WHERE id=".$object->id;
mysql_query($query);
```

This way you will always send the email to the address  with the smallest count!

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind:

1. Just pick a random email address from your array, don't bother with sending them to each email in order. This is going to be much simpler to implement and is going to give you the same result at scale.

   ```
   $my_emails = array('anemail', ...);
   $selected_email = $my_emails[array_rand($my_emails)];
   ```
2. Increment a counter each time an email is sent, persisting the value in a db table or file or something, then use the modulus of the counter and the number of emails you have to choose from to select an email, e.g.

   ```
   $counter = fetch_counter();
   $my_emails = array('anemail', ...);
   $index = ($counter + count($my_emails)) % count($my_emails);
   $selected_email = $my_emails[$index];
   $counter++;
   store_counter($counter);
   ```

I haven't programmed PHP for years so YMMV. You have been warned ;)

Comment: If you need persistence the second option I have suggested would work. Obviously you'd need to implement the persistence code, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it :) I thought about going with an array shift, but will stick to the random method. thanks!

Comment: Great, if this answers your question, can you accept it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find out similarities of the submission and share this. Then you can build a tree and use a greedy algorithm to distribute the e-mail. The problem looks like a bin-packing or vm sharing.